# sticky menu div doensn't stay centered when stuck

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu bar in a `<DIV>` that should stick to the top of the browser when scrolled down.

This works, using JQuery

```
var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyheader').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function()
{
  if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
     $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
     $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block')
  } 
  else {
     $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
     $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

However, the `<DIV>` is centered using CSS: `margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;` and somehow this breaks when the menu is stuck?

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p77dK/1/)

Comment: it's because it has `position:fixed`. you need to learn CSS in order to understand how this works. it would be easy to tell you how to fix it, but my guess is that you need to first learn basics or u'll get stuck with more things after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting to position `fixed` and `top: 0` (by default `left: 0` is added also). Add `left: 50%; margin-left: -100px` and it will work.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p77dK/3/)

Comment: Thanks, solved it. I wasn't aware that left:0 was added with top:0.

Comment: No problem. That's default for positioned elements. You can add only `position: fixed` and it will stick to top left corner.

Comment: hi , your fiddle, has the same defaut than my prior one if you scroll back down, fixed here restoring margin : http://jsfiddle.net/p77dK/7/ (yep i'm a bit slow writing :) )

Comment: The JSFiddle was just a test, using the 200px width. On the actual website the menu bar spans to full width up until 1600px and then the menu bar is centered. On an iPad the code above (corrected to `margin-left:-800px`) did not work. However, the following css `$('#stickyheader').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', right: '0', left: '0'});`worked responsively in all browsers/widths.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you use classes since will make code clear and you can customize it faster.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p77dK/5/)

HTML

```
<div id="stickyheader">
  <div class="bar">BAR</div>
</div>
<div id="stickyalias" class="hidden"></div>
```

JS

```
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) 
            {
                $('#stickyheader').addClass('fixed');
                $('#stickyalias').removeClass('hidden');                 
            } 
            else 
            {
                $('#stickyheader').removeClass('fixed');
                $('#stickyalias').addClass('hidden');
            }
```

CSS

```
#stickyheader {
  width: 100%;
}
#stickyheader.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 8px;/*body margin*/
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
}
#stickyalias {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
}
#stickyalias.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method with positive coordonates and negative margin.
http://jsfiddle.net/p77dK/2/
update : to restore margin once scrolling back down http://jsfiddle.net/p77dK/7/
these are communly used to center absolute elements.

```
var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyheader').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function()
        {
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) 
                {
                    $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', margin: '0 -100px',left:'50%'});
                        $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
                        // also set content top padding under menu
                } 
                else 
                {
                        $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'static', top: '0px',  margin: '0 auto'});
                        $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
                }
        });
```

**other way to do it.**

fixed container can as well be used as a wrapper and show a scrollbar if needed . bar is then in as in a regular container and can be centered with `margin:auto;`
http://jsfiddle.net/p77dK/6/